# How to I add a variable called "moneyness" that takes TRUE when out of money and FALSE otherwise?

Tags: r, finance

Here is the code I have so far that is working:
'''
library(quantmod)
getSymbols(Symbols="^VIX")
VIX=data.frame(VIX)
head(VIX)
tail(VIX)

```
getQuote("^VIX")


vix_opt=getOptionChain("^VIX")
#head(vix_opt1$calls)
vix_opt1=getOptionChain("^VIX", c("2020-10-28","2021-03-17"))
names(vix_opt1)

vix_optall=getOptionChain("^VIX", NULL)
names(vix_optall)


pricefunc <- function(x){
  x$calls$Price <- 0.5*(x$calls$Bid + x$calls$Ask)
  x$puts$Price <- 0.5*(x$puts$Bid + x$puts$Ask)
  return(x)
}

vix_optall=lapply(vix_optall, pricefunc)
names(vix_optall$Nov.04.2020$puts)
head(vix_optall$Nov.04.2020$puts)
```

'''

The next part of the question is:
For calls and puts at each expiration, add a column of ”moneyness”, which
takes value TRUE when it is out-of-money, and FALSE otherwise.
(A call option is out-of-money when its strike is greater than current price
of underlying. A put option is out-of-money if its strike is less than current
price of underlying. And the current price of underlying is from the second
question)

I have tried different loops, and keep getting error when trying to add this column.

Comment: Did my suggestion answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this after your code and insert the current price of VIX for "lastprice":

```
moneynessFunc <- function(x, lastprice = 20){
  x[]$calls$moneyness <- ifelse(x$calls$Strike < lastprice, T, F)
  x[]$puts$moneyness <- ifelse(x$puts$Strike > lastprice, T, F)
  return(x)
}

vix_optall2 <- lapply(vix_optall, moneynessFunc, lastprice = 33)
```